Loading an image to fill max height in a lazyverticalgrid
This is compose kmp project using KamelImage

I have the following that is being loading in my LazyVerticalGrid. However, some of the poster images that are loaded are not of the same height. I have tried to adjust but couldn't get it to work correctly
Here is the image, and you can see that one image is shorter than the others. I want this to match the height so its the same as all the others.
fun MovieListItem(
    movie: MovieResult,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        KamelImage(
            resource = { asyncPainterResource(data = movie.posterPath) },
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
            onLoading = {_ ->
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                    color = Color.Blue
                )
            },
            onFailure = {
                Image(imageVector = vectorResource(Res.drawable.compose_multiplatform), contentDescription = null)
            },
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .background(color = getRandomColor().copy(alpha = 0.4f))
                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            maxLines = 2,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            text = movie.title,
            color = Color.Black)
    }
}


If you want your image to take up the remaining space when the text has a height of 60.dp  so that your columns have equal heights. How about setting your  KamelImage weight to 1 ( modifier = Modifier.weight(1f) ) and contentScale to ContentScale.FillBounds or ContentScale.FillHeight

try with using contentScale = ContentScale.Crop

Try this:

modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
contentScale = ContentScale.Crop


this is a chatgpt copy paste

That doesn't really work for me by setting the height to 200dp. As that makes all the images too short. Bascially, I want to know if I could scale the aspect ratio to all images will be equal size without having a fixed height.

This is what solved my issue by setting the FillHeight and the aspect ratio
i.e.
 modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(2f / 3f),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,

